# "While I had/have had discussion with him about this, no decision has been made."

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

example 1: While I ***have had***  discussion with him about this, no decision has been made.
example 2: While I ***had***  discussion to him about this, no decision has been made.

My understanding is that in example 1, ***have had*** is used to emphasize that there were more than one discussion. In example 2, only one discussion.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite: it's not as simple as you're thinking, unfortunately.

When you use the present perfect ("have had"), you are *choosing* to present the events as having some present relevance. When you use the simple past ("had"), you are *choosing* to present the events as being complete in the past.

Your choice does not necessarily depend on the objective reality: often, you can make either choice about a particular event or sequence of events.

The exact meaning of this "present relevance" is not determined: it can have various meanings.

In this case, if you use "have had", one possible interpretation is that you are regarding the discussion(s) as part of a sequence continuing up to the present: that is consistent with there being more than one discussion, but it does not definitely imply it. It might imply that, although you have had only one discussion with him, you are expecting some more.

Alternatively, the present relevance might mean that, even though you say no decision has been made, there is some outcome of the discussions which is still relevant: perhaps he indicated that he might be open to further discussion, even though you have no particular plans for them.

The simple past means that you are choosing to present the discussions as complete. This *might* mean that he has indicated that he is not interested in any further discussions. Or it might mean, that as far as you are concerned, there is no point in any further discussions. Or it might mean that, for the purposes of the current conversation, you are not concerned with anything other than the fact that the discussions have taken place.

One further point: "discussion" in the sense of "individual instance of discussing" is countable, so you need either *a discussion*, or *discussions*. You also need *with him*, as in your first example, not *to him*.